# How can I add xml file to the classpath in intelliJ IDEA without any builders like Maven?

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, intellij-idea, classpath

I want to create Spring-hibernate integration without any types of builders and helpers like Maven, Gradle, Ant, Spring-initializer ant other stuff. Only using IntelijIdea, jars and xml.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Put yours xml to any folder.
2. Click File -> Project structure -> Modules.
3. In Source sub tab select your resource folder and mark this folder as 'Resources' pushing by 'Resources'-button.

[image]